# in gvim, how to disable scrollbar when taglist is shown?

Tags: vim, taglist

i've set "set guioptions-=l", but whenever taglist is enabled the left hand scrollbar is still shown and cannot be disabled (right hand scrollbar toggles fine). also, vim wont maximize on start if taglist is enabled.

if the above can't be fixed, are there any taglist altenatives.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you have `guioptions-=L` set too. If it's not removed then you'll get a left hand scrollbar whenever there's a vertical split.

Answer (score 7):

I use this in my .gvimrc.

```
set guioptions=Ace
```

Comment: this is actually more useful.