# How to disable the windows gvim vertical scroolbar in the vimrc file?

Tags: vim

In Windows 7, my Gvim version 7.4 has a vertical scroll bar on the right side of the edit area, even if the edit area is not scrollable.

I want is disable it completely, no matter if the edit area is scrollable or not, to make a larger edit area by writing the settings in the vim.rc file so the settings will persist.

I searched but cannot find an answer in:

- [in gvim, how to disable scrollbar when taglist is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984035/in-gvim-how-to-disable-scrollbar-when-taglist-is-shown)
- https://superuser.com/questions/198981/show-gvim-scrollbar-only-when-needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is(maybe `r` means rightside?):

```
:set guioptions-=r
```

**Update:**

From `:help guioptions` we can learn details about all possible options.

Comment: Just use embedded vim help system `:help 'guioptions'`

Comment: "By the way, does anybody know what does set guioptions-=b do?" Please don't ask questions in answers. Instead, create a separate question for that only. Stack Overflow isn't a message-list, it's an online encyclopedia, where each separate question is a separate article with associated fixes or solutions.